# C# find directory arg in commandline

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, directory, arguments

I'm new to C# and trying to find the directory arg in commandline. For example, if I type

*dotnet run -- -f c:\example\exampleFolder -v OR dotnet run -- -f -v c:\example\exampleFolder*

It should detect **exampleFolder** directory no matter which arg position it is at and set it to the current working directory.
So far, I have this in my Main method...

```
foreach(var path in args)
{
    FileAttribute attr = File.GettAttributes.Directory(path);
    if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
    {
        //
        // Directory.SetCurrentDirectory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attributes, you can use `Directory.Exists`.

Also, it's not clear what OS you're running this under, because you have a `$` prompt, which suggests some kind of Linux system, but you're not escaping your slashes.

Comment: Edited. sorry my bad! I'm using Windows.